# ADB 'unauthorized' on Samsung Galaxy Note 8

Tags: android, macos, adb, samsung-galaxy

I have a new Samsung Galaxy Note 8 and trying to send `adb` commands to it from a Mac OS X laptop, but I have not managed to get beyond the device being listed as `unauthorized` when I execute `adb devices`.  I've tried to `rm -rf ~/.android` and refresh that folder with the adb keys by rerunning `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`, and I have also made sure developer mode on my Android device is on and I executed the `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` button, but still with no success.  I also updated the Android OS to the latest version.  Any advice?  These are the suggestions I have found online but none have worked for me…

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this by turning off then back on again the `USB debugging` mode after I updated the OS (i.e., updating to Android 8.0.0 then just-revoking the USB debugging authorizations did not work (since the `USB debugging` mode was already on), but instead toggling off-then-on-again the `USB debugging` mode and then revoking the USB debugging authorizations *did work*).